# Gradle equivalent to 'grails -Dgrails.env=production run-app'

Tags: grails, gradle, grails-3.1, gradle-task

I'm upgrading my Grails 2.5.1 web-app to Grails 3.1.1.
To run the app locally with `production` as active environment I used

```
grails -Dgrails.env=production run-app
```

Now I'm using Gradle tasks, in particular `gradle bootRun`.

What's the easiest equivalent to the previous syntax?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's `gradle -Dgrails.env=prod bootRun`

Comment: By the way, use `gradle tasks` to list all available tasks. After installing plugins new tasks may be available.

Comment: If you have a graddle wrapper, `./gradlew bootRun -Dgrails.env=prod`